# JPA @Past Date/Calendar validation

Tags: java, hibernate, date, jpa, jackson

In a spring-boot based project i have a simple DTO object:

```
public class ExpenseDTO {

    @Min(value = 1, message = "expense.amount.negative")
    private int amount;

    @Past
    private Calendar createdAt;

    // setters/getters/constructor are omitted
}
```

and such rest controller:

```
public class ExpenseController {

private final ExpenseService expenseService;

    @Autowired
    public ExpenseController(ExpenseService expenseService) {
        this.expenseService = expenseService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = ADD_EXPENSE, method = POST)
    public ResponseEntity addExpense(@Valid @RequestBody ExpenseDTO expenseDTO, Principal principal) {
        expenseService.addExpense(expenseDTO, principal.getName());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

From a client i'm gonna send a current date: {"createdAt": "2017-01-27T21:32:19.183Z"} but during validation on the back end the date will be parsed as "2017-01-28T01:30:00.000+0200" so the result is wrong and validation fails. I was trying to play around with @JsonFormat but with no result.

NOTE: i'm using H2 db and if remove @Past from the DTO object everything works just fine, but i have to disable future date.

So how can i validate the date without timezone, i mean i need the exactly the same date on the back end as it was send from a client?!

Comment: If client is sending `2017-01-27T21:32:19.183Z`, how did that get converted to `2017-01-28T01:30:00.000+0200`? That is not even close to being the same time. `2017-01-27T23:32:19.183+0200` would be the same time.

Comment: @Andreas i think it's because on my JVM timezone is GMT+2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because of the `TimeZone` set in your local machine. You can set it to `UTC` in the application startup, e.g.:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Also, you need to set the `TimeZone` in the `SimpleDateFormat` instance that is being configured inside `ObjectMapper` (if you are configuring `ObjectMapper` as a bean), e.g.:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    objectMapper.setDateFormat(simpleDateFormat);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

If it still does not work, I would recommend creating a custom deserializer for Calendar and manually setting `TimeZone` in new instance, e.g.:

```
@Component
public class CalendarDeserialiser extends JsonDeserializer<Calendar>{

    TimeZone UTC = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

    @Override
    public Calendar deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        Calendar calendar;
        try{
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance(UTC);
            calendar.setTime(dateFormat.parse(p.getText()));
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(p.getLongValue());
        return calendar;
    }
}
```

And annotate your `Calendar` field with `@JsonDeserialize(using = CalendarDeserialiser.class)`.

Comment: Now with CalendarDeserialiser the date is in UTC time zone but validation for @Past still fails

Comment: None of that explains how `21:32Z` became `01:30+0200`, when it obviously should be `23:32+0200`. Where did the 2 minutes disappear to, and why is it 2 hours off? I don't know the details of the `@Past` validation, but assuming `21:32Z` was in the past at the time of the validation, `23:32+0200` would also have been in the past, since it's the exact same physical time. The problem is not timezone, but the *corruption* of the value from `23:32+0200` to `01:30+0200` of the following day.

Comment: So, now Past validation works just fine, i used CalendarDeserialiser but forgot remove 
PostConstruct
    public void started() {
        setDefault(getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }

But in the DB i have stored date with minus 2 hours